# Javascript Function not working Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have this code, but when I call it in the html, it does not do anything in wordpress.
How can I fix this> Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript">
var l1OK_WC = false;
var l2OK_WC = false;
function share()
{
   alert('yo');
}
function getIt_wc()
{
   if(l1OK_WC)
      window.open('http://google.ca','_self');

   if(!l1OK_WC)
      alert("Message 1");
   else if(!l2OK_WC)
      alert("Message 2");
}
</script>
```

And this in the html.

```
<a class="Style3" href="javascript:getIt_wc();"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XJy0nEq.png" /></a>
```

When I click the button, no message appears. This script works fine in blogger or html sites, but not on wordpress.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in wordpress too. Check console for other js errors.